# lstlistoflistings is unformatted

Tags: formatting, listings, minted

I habe a problem to get a list of listings that looks like the normale table of figures or basically like any other list of anything. As I am not a tex or latex pro, i tried several packages and snippet from the web with no success (including tocloft btw.).

Update:
Here is the complete document (I stripped the content and further headlines)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{minted}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{bg2}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,format=plain,margin=0pt, skip=0pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1mm}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}
\newcommand{\gq}[1]{\glqq{#1}\grqq}

\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Listingsverzeichnis}

\begin{document}

\input{title.tex}
\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\lhead{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}

\newpage

\thispagestyle{plain}
\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listingsverzeichnis}

\newpage

\section{Headline XYZ}

\begin{listing}
\inputminted[linenos,frame=lines,framerule=0.5pt,framesep=8pt,rulecolor=\color{black!100},bgcolor=bg,numbersep=10pt,fontfamily=zi4,fontsize=\footnotesize,xleftmargin=-2pt]{javascript}{listings/test.js}
\caption{app/app.js}
\end{listing}
\newpage

\begin{figure}
\caption{Example Image Caption I}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/abstract.jpg}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Example Image II}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/abstract.jpg}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\end{document}
```

This is what `\lstlistoflistings` produces (it is: "number captionpage"):
[image]

And this is what it SHOULD look like:
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please modify the code in the question. Remove all non essential elements and then make it a *complete* document allowing us to easily reproduce the problem mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code.

Comment: Your update is uncompilable. Please update

Comment: Also your mwe should be compilable on its own. This isn't refers to images we do not have. Consider the `[demo]` option for `graphicx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest fix is to `\let` the listing entries be formatted as figure entries using

```
\makeatletter
\let\l@listing\l@figure
\makeatother
```

I reduced the original code even further up to almost a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{1,1,1}
\definecolor{bg2}{rgb}{0.6,0.6,0.6}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{inconsolata}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{listings}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Listingsverzeichnis}

\makeatletter
\let\l@listing\l@figure
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}

\lstlistoflistings
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Listingsverzeichnis}


\section{Test section}

\begin{listing}
\caption{A test caption for a listing}
\end{listing}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Example Image Caption I}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Example Image II}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is it normal for the list of figures and the list of tables to be farther to the right?, this is my question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461263/how-aligned-table-of-content